# Refractive index, wavenumber, and wave impedance of the PEC that a plane wave is normally incident on

Tags: impedance, wave, dielectric, conductors, reflection

I am trying to find the refractive index \$n_t\$, wavenumber \$k_t\$, and wave impedance \$\eta_t\$ of a perfect electric conducting medium t. Here is my work so far:

1. The conductivity of the PEC is \$\sigma_t=\infty\$.
2. The intrinsic electric permittivity of the PEC is \$\epsilon_t=\infty\$.
3. Effective electric permittivity of a conductor is \$\epsilon_{\text{t,eff}}(\omega)=\epsilon_t\left(1-j\frac{\sigma_t}{\omega\epsilon_t}\right)=\infty-j\infty\$.
4. Effective refractive index of a conductor is \$n_{\text{t,eff}}(\omega)=\sqrt{\frac{\epsilon_{\text{t,eff}}\,(\omega)}{\epsilon_o}}=\infty-j\infty\$.
5. Effective wavenumber of a conductor is \$k_{\text{t,eff}}(\omega)=\frac{\omega\,n_{\text{t,eff}}\,(\omega)}{c}=\infty-j\infty\$.
6. Effective wave impedance is \$\eta_{\text{t,eff}}(\omega)=\sqrt{\frac{\mu_o}{\epsilon_{\text{t,eff}}\,(\omega)}}=\frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}\sqrt{1+j}}{\sqrt{\infty}}=0\$.

It makes sense that the impedance would be 0 but what about the other two properties?

Answer (score 1):

- Wave number is a property of a wave, not of the medium it travels in. It makes no sense to ask what is the wave number of a material.
- No electromagnetic wave can travel in PEC (because its conductivity is infinite and the skin depth of any wave reflecting off it is 0), so it makes no sense to ask what is its refractive index.
- Similarly, since no electromagnetic wave can travel in PEC, it makes no sense to ask what is the wave impedance in PEC. (Your result that the impedance is zero may be useful for determining the phase shift of the reflection)

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding about the wavenumber. To evaluate it I used the dispersion relation for conductors. All of the equations I used above are what I thought were to be used when talking about conductive mediums; whether or not it "makes sense" to talk about these 3 properties, they should still have a definitive result, as a PEC is just the extreme case of the conductor.

Comment: I am still interested in calculating their values correctly as I feel they provide value in being able to prove certain things, e.g., that the wave impedance is 0.

Comment: There's nothing to calculate. It's like asking to calculate the "speed of empty space" or the "height of the color blue".

Comment: You can relate the imaginary part of the permittivity to the resistivity, and take the limit as \$\rho\to\infty\$; but it will tell you nothing about the real part.

Comment: That is one way to express it, yes. I think what I got for \$k_t\$ is probably correct because it produces the correct reflection coefficient when medium i is free space with \$k_i=\frac{\omega}{c}\$: \$\Gamma = \frac{\frac{k_i}{k_t} - 1}{\frac{k_i}{k_t} + 1}=-1\$.